# elastic search wildcards in phrases

Tags: elasticsearch

Currently we have a search that does literal full word search. For example in the documents

Hello world
Hello world again
Hello beautiful world
The world says hello

```
q="Hell" returns nothing
q="Hello" returns all 4
q="Hello w" returns nothing
q="hello world" returns the first 2
```

We now need to do wildcard matching. We can achieve this with * and removing the quotes from around the query. However, removing the quotes also stops the lookup from being a phrase lookup. For example

```
q=Hell* returns all 4 (not a problem)
q=Hello w* returns all 4 (problem; we wanted only the first two)
```

Is anyone aware of a way to prevent the split of "hello" and "w*" into 2 separate searches?

Answer (score 0):

Change **q** type to keyword is one solution and then create a lowercase normalizer.

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "doc": {
      "properties": {
        "q": {
          "type": "text",
          "fields": {
            "keyword": {
              "type": "keyword",    
              "normalizer": "my_custom_normalizer"
            }
          },
          "fielddata": true
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "normalizer": {
        "my_custom_normalizer": {
          "type": "custom",
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Search query:

```
GET index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "q.keyword": {
        "value": "hello w*"
      }
    }
  }
}
```